# Web browser running in vps

Tags: linux, centos, vps

I'm curious if is there any way we can run an entire web browser in centos 7 based vps

I know it's kind of strange thing to do but one the project required this specifically and does not find any useful stuff on internet

We just wanted a web browser or maybe remote pc which we can access and pay hourly basis where we can open a website, on server itself execute all js and stuff like it do in normal pc

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing special about that. You can set that up yourself with e.g. a VNC server on the Vps. Or, you can even directly rent in-The-cloud workstations from multiple cloud vendors.

Comment: thanks for help man, will read about this stuff more, thanks

Comment: SSH with X-forwarding would be another possibility.